# Electrical wiring capped with wire connectors exposed to weather: bad idea?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety

I noticed what appears to be electrical wiring exposed at the peak of the gable end of our office. I don't have any way to know if there's current flowing to those wires.

Is that a problem?  I assume that it isn't a good long-term thing, but I guess I can't actually back that up. Anybody?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI any exposed conductors should be protected and covered no matter where they occur. Especially if the exposed wiring is on an exterior where the insulation is exposed to a more severe environment.

Comment: R.M.E can you provide a code ref since protected by elevation is an example where they do not require anything additional 110.27.A.4  live parts can be protected by elevation 8’ for up to 300v between ungrounded conductors.

Comment: @EdBeal - Please make note that I did not mention any NEC requirement. It is important to note that the NEC is a MINIMUM STANDARD. The fact that you exceed the NEC is not a violation especially when it promotes safety and practicality. And in this case given you are giving it to someone who might not have any particular skill set in this area.  The idea of protection is one of the main reasons for the NEC and can be found throughout the NEC.

Comment: In the case you suggest someone not having the skills or experience it would be safer to do nothing as there is no hazard to anyone the way it is.

Comment: @EdBeal - You can post that as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere there are electrical wires with wire nuts or other type of splice, the splice should be in a coverable pertinent junction box whether inside or out. That's code as far as I know and a basic commonsense safety practice at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

If you are renting you might want to ask the owner if there's supposed to be a flood light fixture up there. It looks light a perfect spot for one. 
The wires are high up so there's no immediate threat but they're not supposed to be like that so they should be fixed with a plate cover.

Can the wires be accessed from that top room or attic?

Comment: I would be more concerned about rain entering the structure at the opening. As far as is it legal live open conductors can be protected by elevation, there are wire nuts so there won’t be any current flow. Where this probably be a code violation is the wire is most likely Romex or NMB cable and NMB cable is not listed for a wet location, the paper separators in the cable will wick any water back to a junction box or service panel.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to reach the wires except a 3 story tall ladder or scaffolding.

Comment: @EdBeal  I'm approaching my three year mark. I've learned so much from you. What I've always noticed is that you've done the work you're commenting on. It's obvious from your answers that you're a pro.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I am an active supervising electrician, some don’t like my answers or comments but I try to keep them code based and try to keep opinion out maybe not so well at times but with 40 years of general construction & electrical experience in residential, commercial and industrial I have worked in many areas. Just missing utility power generators but maybe who knows.